# Replace an existing image with a new image on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

The user has an option to change or update the profile image. I want to replace new image with the old. I don't want to keep both images in storage. Or can we delete old image if the user updates the image?

Image storage view:

[image: Image storage view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the same reference of the image to replace it, no need to explicitly delete then upload the new image.

So if a user's image resides at `UserProfile/user123.jpg`, then you just have to grab their profile image reference and use it as the destination for an upload.

```
StorageReference userProfileRef = storageRef.child("UserProfile/user123.jpg");
```

Then upload the image to that reference with whatever method you use - Glide, UploadTask, etc. It will overwrite automatically. It does change the url of the image as well, in case that's important.